# Android - EditText custom style

Tags: android, android-layout

I haven't used custom styles before. I want to customize the style of EditText on my app to be exactly like in the image below.

[image]

I'm not asking you to design it for me. Just point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use layer list for styling. Create this file in drawable folder `bg_search.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item>
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
           <corners android:radius="5dp" />
           </shape>
    </item>

     <item
       android:bottom="2dp"
       android:left="1dp"
       android:right="1dp">
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
           <corners android:radius="5dp" />
           </shape>
      </item>
  </layer-list>
```

and apply as a background of your `EditText`

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_search"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:hint="Search SoundCloud"
        android:padding="16dp" />
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Happy coding :)